# CEFSharp support for ECMAScript 2020 (ES 11)

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

we use the CEFSharp browser for our application.

One of our client pages that we connect with is now using ECMAScript 2020 (ES 11), and our version of CEFSharp does not support it.

My research has suggested that it was introduced in CEFSharp version 80, however, I cannot find confirmation.

Can anyone suggest which version we should update to in order to support ECMAScript 2020 (ES 11) in CEFSharp, while maintaining backwards compatibility.

Thank-you

**UPDATE: Currently we are using CEFSharp 79.1.350.0, I want to update to the latest, but it looks like a lot of potential breaking changes that we will have to make to our application**

Comment: I am thinking I will just upgrade to CEFShap v119.1.20.

The documentation (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v119.1.20 ) does not mention the supported ECMAScript 2020 (V11), or any details on ECMAScript.

For now I will make the assumption that it supports this.
Please let me know if you encountered any upgrade troubles... with going from 79 to 119 I feel like I should expect breaking-changes.

If anyone has experience here, please share your thoughts.

Thank you again so much.
I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown by [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=es2020), Chromium v80 supports all of the mentioned features ([optional chaining](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining) `?.` and [nullish coalescing](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing) `??` operators support was added in v80).

So CEFSharp v80 would be enough but it might have vulnerabilities that the latest version might not have so I recommend you upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you @Valentin, this was my main concern.
I will continue upgrading with the latest 119 version.
_     
I know they changed how some of the PAK files work, but eventually we will need to do this upgrade anyway, so I agree, especially for security reasons that using the latest stable ps, the numbers 1 and 9 are my favorite numbers, so that settles it, I will upgrade to v119!     
Thank you again for answering my questions.

Comment: Also, thank you for the caniuse.com link, I will forward this resource to our team as it seem very useful!